# homepage entry in the package.json gving error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, package.json

I am running react app in the nginx server by dockerizing it.

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-axios": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build-window": "react-scripts build && del ../server/dist && move build ../server/dist",
    "build-linux": "react-scripts build && rm -rf ../server/dist && mv build ../server/dist",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "homepage": "/myapp/"
}
```

if i dont put homepage entry i am able to run locally but in the ngInx server, css and js files are giving 404.

below is the path it is taking without context path in ngInx server for css https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/static/css/main.9a46c0ad.css

If i put homepage entry , i am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error . But in the network tab i see all the js and css files are loading properly..

Can you please help me, which area i have to concentrate to resolve this issue

Comment: Are you trying to set the context of your application?

Comment: yes as "myapp". Even i tried by putting '.'. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your context root in the `package.json`. When you build the app you can give the the base-href in your build script. Add `--base-href=/myapp/` in your build script. This will add the base href in your index.html

Comment: I have tried it but in the server , not able to load css and js files. Getting 404 error.